# Panel data cointegration test: Package pco R, how to interpret output from pedroni99 function?

Tags: r, statistics, panel-data

I have a panel dataset and I want to test cointegration between 2 variables. I cleaned the missing values and set my data frame as required but I don't know how to interpret the results/ outcome from the pedroni test on R, the outcome looks like this:

[image]

And why do I have NaN in some cases ?

(I already read the paper, help and documentation attached)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).  Also, you maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: If you need help interpreting results from statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.